# Rails I18n. Set "en" default_locale with "es-CL" as locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have two locale files:

1. config/locales/en.yml
2. config/locales/es-cl.yml

I want to use "en" as default locale to translate to English language when "es-CL" translations are missing. So, this is my application.rb file:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = ['en', 'es-CL']
config.i18n.default_locale = 'en'
config.i18n.locale = 'es-CL'
```

On production.rb

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

But, when I start server, locales are on English language.

A chunk of my es-cl.yml (the translation is working when I set **config.i18n.default_locale** to "es-CL")

```
es-CL:
  activerecord:
    models:
      admin_user:
        one: Administrador
        other: Administradores
      producer:
        one: Productora
        other: Productoras
      ticket:
        one: Ticket
        other: Tickets
```

Comment: Hey,

can you give a little more infos:

* please post the code where you can I18n.translate
* you are talking about production.rb, are you running the server in dev or prod mode?
* do you get a 'i18n key not found' in dev mode?

Comment: I'm setting config.i18n.fallbacks = true in production env because I want English translations if I forget to add some Spanish(es-CL) key=value. I'm not sure If It'is correct to do this with fallbacks... I want this working on production env. On development I want to see the message "translation missing: es-CL...."

Answer (score 0):

The locale set in the config i.e `config.locale = :es` is not persistent. You will have to set the locale before request e.g in application_controller.

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || 'es'
end
```